# Problema na verificação entre duas variáveis em python

Tags: python, loop

Este código é feito para gerar uma senha de X números aleatória(1 no caso), e depois fazer um loop de senhas aleatórias até chegar na senha inicial, "bruteforce". Apesar de ele conseguir gerar a primeira senha e a função para gerar senhas aleatórias também funcionar, o código não detecta quando a senha gerada pela função é igual a senha inicial. O problema deve ser bem trivial, sou iniciante.

```
import random

low = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

upper = low.upper()

mix = low + upper

password_list = random.sample(mix, 1)

password = ''.join(password_list)


def random_bet():

    try_list = random.sample(mix, 1)

    guess = ''.join(try_list)

    return guess


while random_bet() != password:

    print(random_bet())

    print(password)

    print('Wrong')

    if random_bet() == password:

        print(random_bet(), password)

        print('right')

        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que vc chama `random_bet()` ele pode retornar um valor diferente.

Seu `while` e `if` são "sobrepostos"

Use conforme abaixo

```
bet = random_bet()

while bet != password:
    print(bet)
    print(password)
    print('Wrong')
    bet = random_bet()


print(bet, password)
print('right')
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Valeu Mesmo, funcionou